# my react app contains p5 sketches that keep repeating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js, use-ref

I am currently stuck trying to implement p5 sketches into my React App. I have attempted to change the z Index of the toolbar so that the p5 elements sit underneath, however when I do this they keep repeating. You can see a link to the repository [here](https://github.com/harryw123545/website-second-draft) (the sketches are in the bio and contact folders).

I understand that this is likely to do with the instance mode of the sketches, however I am very new to React and I am unfamiliar with the right syntax.

If anyone has any advice please feel free to get in touch!

Comment: You should try to reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If possible add it to your question as a runnable snippet, and if that isn't possible, include the pertinent parts of your code as formatted code blocks and link to a runnable instance of your code somewhere like replit.com or glitch.com

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue, but here is a significantly simplified version of your React app in a form that can be embedded in StackOverflow:

```js
// Modification: Pass the container element to a function when returns the
// actual sketch function. This way we don't have to get the container
// element by id.
const bioSketch = (container) => {
  return (p) => {
    p.setup = () => {
      let c = p.createCanvas(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
      // This was missing from your code, so that may have been causing problems.
      // An alternative to setting the canvas parent this way is to pass the
      // parent to the p5 constructor.
      c.parent(container);

      p.angleMode(p.DEGREES);
      p.rectMode(p.CENTER);
    }

    p.draw = () => {
      p.background(0, 20);
      let time = p.frameCount;
      let iter = p.map(p.accelerationX, -90, 90, 0, 3);
      let col = p.map(p.accelerationY, -90, 90, 0.02, 3.5);

      p.translate(p.width / 2, p.height / 2);

      for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        p.push();
        p.rotate(p.cos(p.frameCount + i * iter) * 80);
        p.stroke(127 + 127 * p.sin(i * col + time), 127 + 127 * p.sin(i * 2 + time), 127 + 127 * p.sin(i * 0.5 + time));
        p.noFill();
        p.rect(0, 0, 620 - i * 3.12, 620 - i * 3.12, 200 - i);
        p.pop();
      }
    }

    p.windowResized = () => {
      p.resizeCanvas(canvas.offsetWidth, canvas.offsetHeight)
      p.background(0);
    }
  }
}

function Bio() {
  const containerRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('initializing effect');
    const sketch = new p5(bioSketch(containerRef.current));

    // The return value form useEffect is a callback to remove the effect
    return () => {
      console.log('cleaning up effect');
      sketch.remove();
    }
  }, []);

  return <div id='canvas-container' ref={containerRef} />;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { showSketch: true };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.state.showSketch && <Bio />}
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showSketch: this.state.showSketch ? false : true })}>
        Toggle
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
#canvas-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This looks like it is basically working to me, so obviously I have gone too far in simplifying the code and removed whatever was causing the issue. It is up to you to introduce just enough to demonstrate the issue without over complicating things with extraneous components and styles and routing.

For more info on how to embed ReactJS code in a StackOverflow question see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I added the code you suggested in the setup function (let c = p.createCanvas) and it appears to have solved the issue of the p5 sketches repeating across different pages. They appear to still be drawing new instances of the sketch over the top of each other when you click on each tab however, causing them to slow down. Is there a way of effectively erasing each element when it isnt being used? I assume that may be to do with the useRef() ?

Comment: @Harry I've updated my example to show how to clean up your effect. I also improved the sketch component by making it use a ref for the container element in order to eliminate the use of `getElementById()`.